# How to automatically choose an account in an android test?

Tags: android, android-intent, accountmanager

I have an application where I have to automate testing. At the start, the application asks the user to select an account before it can proceed. Here's my code:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("com.google.android.gms.common.account.CHOOSE_ACCOUNT");
    Intent result = new Intent();

    result.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME,TEST_EMAIL);
    getInstrumentation().addMonitor(filter, new ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result), true);
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
    solo.assertCurrentActivity("MainActivity is not the current activity.", MainActivity.class);

    Database.db().wipe();
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
```

Supposedly, this code would capture the request for an account, give it a predefined email, and proceed. What actually happens is that when I run the test, the emulator shows the account dialog, selects the correct account (TEST_EMAIL) but then just stops there instead of letting the application go on. Am I missing something?